# What is causing a pause during the system device probe?

Tags: freebsd, hardware, startup

I am running FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE.

During the boot device probe there is a two-times 30 second pause. The output relevant to this is

```
# dmesg
...
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): ATAPI_IDENTIFY. ACB: a1 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): CAM status: Command timeout
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): Error 5, Retry was blocked
run_interrupt_driven_hooks: still waiting after 60 seconds for xpt_config
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): ATAPI_IDENTIFY. ACB: a1 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): CAM status: Command timeout
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): Error 5, Retry was blocked
...
```

I am quite new to this OS but does this mean the system is detecting a device but cannot figure out what it is? I have nothing but the bare essentials attached - hard drive and optical drive and is confirmed with:

```
# camcontrol devlist
<MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ-841S 1.00>     at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (pass0,cd0)
<HGST HTS7250xxxxxxxx GHB0xxxx>     at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,ada0)
```

I tried some other commands to get some additional information:

```
# camcontrol rescan all
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): ATAPI_IDENTIFY. ACB: a1 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): CAM status: Command timeout
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): Error 5, Retry was blocked
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): ATAPI_IDENTIFY. ACB: a1 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): CAM status: Command timeout
(aprobe0:ata0:0:1:0): Error 5, Retry was blocked
Re-scan of bus 0 was successful
Re-scan of bus 1 was successful
Re-scan of bus 2 was successful
Re-scan of bus 3 was successful
Re-scan of bus 4 was successful
```

With `camcontrol rescan all` the system again pauses twice for 30 seconds before it rescans the buses. Even if I request to scan just a single bus the system insists on doing the 'aprobe0' scan first. Also, the "aprobe0..." lines are bold and bright white which someone told me means it is a kernel response. I would be happy if I could even just reduce the length of the pauses. I tried entering `kern.cam.ada.default_timeout=5` in `/boot/loader.conf` but it did not have any effect. I have searched long and hard without success and can't get much help. Anyone who knows better have any ideas? Thanks!

Just to add, this is RELEASE-10. For a short while before this I was running RELEASE-8.3 which worked perfectly with no delays. The boot process took something like 15 seconds. But just as I was starting to learn on R8.3, it reached EOL, so I just decided to move up to R10. The ATA kernel modules for R10 are very different from those in R8.3. I have read about such changes but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: ATAPI_IDENTIFY suggests that the problem is the DVD drive. Does the error go away if you boot with a disc in the DVD drive?

Comment: Unfortunately the delay (it is just a delay as the system is functioning fine otherwise - the delay is just really, really annoying) is always there no matter what. Right now I'm actually booting with a disc in the drive to serve as my boot manager because I have a few partitions on the hard drive with no boot manager installed. The disc just passes the booting responsibility to the default FreeBSD boot loader though. The delay was also present on a previous installation that took up the entire hard drive with no disc present in the DVD drive at startup.

Answer (score 1):

All points out to be a bug/regression that started at FreeBSD 9.1

- [kern/173435](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=173435)

And sadly, there is no workaround available. Maybe you could give more details of your issue(hardware, FreeBSD version) on `kern/173435`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a DVD drive would be a da(4) device not an ada(4) device, try lowering `kern.cam.da.default_timeout` in `/boot/loader.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try and there was no change. I also checked that particular default timeout value before I made the change and it was 60. For my problem it seems to be two command timeouts with each being 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are still two things to try:

1. Try to update the DVD drive's firmware. It looks like it uses version 1.00. There is a good chance it has been updated to fix this bug.
2. Remove the drive. It's an old piece of hardware anyway.